# C# openfiledialog.showdialog() automatically returns DialogResult.Cancel without pop up the open file windows

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog, showdialog

I've bind an openfiledialog to a button in my WPF application. Once the button is clicked, it will can a method, which creates a openfiledialog instance and open a file dialogue:

```
           OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            { 
            //do arithmetic operation, nothing to do with the GUI
            }
```

Yet it is found after a number of clicks, the file dialog will not appear, and if I step into the program, I found the method openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() always return to a value DialogResult.Cancel. Any idea on this strange behavior?

Comment: This code is called from a UI thread, right? Not some background thread?

Comment: you added [STAThread]  to the main function right?

Comment: STAThread is added in the main

Comment: rene: the code is called from a UI thread, not background thread